# What Is The Best Method/Tool To Investigate WordPress Internal Performance?

Tags: performance

I have a very basic WordPress site and, using `www.webpagetest.org`, I can see that my site takes around 4 seconds before it transfers a single byte. I've already fixed delays associated with https redirection and caching. What is it doing for these 4 seconds?

The performance test tools are great for looking at transfers between client and server, but how do I analyse what WordPress is doing?

Maybe it just takes that long to process WordPress and all the plugins but I suspect that something is wrong. Maybe a Db query is inefficient, or maybe a php script is timing out?

What is the best method/tool to investigate WordPress internal performance?

Comment: a first thing to do is to deactivate the plugins one by one to test if one is more responsible of this delay.

Comment: @Kaperto This would definitely work but some impact operational functions so my testing would be inconsistent. I'm hoping that there is some way that breaks down those 4 seconds into, for example, plugin x did y and took z seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the queries there run on the pages, with and without plugins and custom Theme. So you have the possibility to compare the process and find the bottlenecks.
As helping tools should I named:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-objects/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Activate the debug mode so that you also get errors and the usage of minified scripts and deactivation of caching. Helpful page is https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: I'll take a good look at these, thank you. I'll post an update soon.